# DateTime + Timer Tick?

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I want, when I click on a button, to start an "elapsed time". I've written this so far:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timeCounter++;
    labelTimer.Text = "Elapsed Time: " + timeCounter.ToString();
}
```

with `timer` interval at 1000 (1 second).

What I want is to format time like this:

```
HH:MM:SS
```

and to auto increment minutes when seconds reach 60, and so on for hours. Should I use DateTime for this and add a second every 1 second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx):

```
TimeSpan _elapsed = new TimeSpan();

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _elapsed = _elapsed.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    labelTimer.Text = "Elapsed Time: " + _elapsed.ToString();
}
```

Comment: And where should I put the declaration of `TimeSpan _elapsed = new TimeSpan();`? Inside the timer_Tick it says it does not exist in the context :O

Comment: It should be a new member of your existing class, you may place it above your timer_Tick() method if you want, as in my example.

Comment: I placed it here, but it doesnt works :O EDIT: `_elasped`, mistype :)

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my example: _elasped => _elapsed. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stopwatch and it's elapsed time to create a datetime (and set it's format as you like).

```
Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();
//Some more operations here...
s.Stop();
DateTime t = new DateTime(s.ElapsedTicks);
```

If you like, you can also set the frequency of the stopwatch in order to minimize the resource consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple way you can use like this:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
       Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

       // Your logics goes Here

       stopWatch.Stop();
       DateTime time = new DateTime(stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
       labelTimer.Text = time.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```